# Insert ASCII in LSB

Tags: matlab, binary, ascii

Does anyone know a efficient method in order to insert the ASCII value of some characters in the 8 least significant bits (LSB) of a 16 bit number?

The only idea that comes up in my mind is to convert both numbers to binary, then replace the last 8 characters, from 16 bit number, by the ASCII value in 8 bits. But as far as I know string operations are very expensive in computational time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MATLAB implementation of @user1118321 idea:

```
%# 16-bit integer number
x = uint16(30000);

%# character
c = 'a';

%# replace lower 8-bit 
y = bitand(x,hex2dec('FF00'),class(x)) + cast(c-0,class(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I'm getting and error using bitand "Too many input arguments", I checked the documentation and everything seems to be fine. Have you tried your code directly in matlab?

Comment: @JorgeZapata: What MATLAB version do you have? the last argument of `bitand` (`assumedType`) was added in recent versions... I guess it is optional here. Just call it as: `bitand(x,hex2dec('FF00'))`

Comment: one could achieve the same using bit shifting

Comment: In fact was the assumed type parameter, I'm using Matlab R2012a for mac. Omitting the assumed type solved the problem. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Matlab syntax, but in C, it would be something like this:

```
short x; // a 16-bit integer in many implementations
... do whatever you need to to x ...
char a = 'a'; // some character
x = (x & 0xFF00) | (short)(a & 0x00FF);
```

The `&` operator is the arithmetic "and" operator. The `|` operator is the arithmetic "or" operator. Numbers beginning with `0x` are in hexadecimal for easy readability.

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer, I'm trying to implement a similar version of your code with the help of Amro. Definitely your code will run faster than the approach in my question